# How to show $\left\{ x \in \mathbb N \mid x \equiv 11 \pmod{15}\right\}$ is countable by establishing a bijection between the set and N

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to show , $\left\{ x \in \mathbb N \mid x \equiv 11 \pmod{15}\right\}$ , is countable by establishing a bijection between the set and $\mathbb N$

Comment: $n \to 11+ 15n$

Comment: As I said on a duplicate-but-for-the-values question asked 5 mins later: What part of the question are you having trouble with? Can you show us where you got stuck, what you've tried, or what tools you have available to answer the question?

Comment: @ConMan Can you tell me If Im on the right track, I know that a set is countable if it is finite or it has the same cardinality as the set of natural numbers, this is were Im lost, because the equation xmod15=11, with no restrictions on x in infinite, but i don't think it has the same cardinality as the set of natural numbers, or does it?

Comment: J. W. Tanner told you that the one to one function is n→11+ 15n. That is not finite because it gives a different value for every n. But is a subset of N.  Yes, it has the same cardinality as N because [b]any[/b] infinite subset of N is has the same cardinality as N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just strung the comments together and this is basically a complete answer but I have left the details for you to fill in.

As is in the comments we can take $\phi(n)=11+15n$ and then we need to argue that $\phi$ is a bijection. This means we need to show that $\phi$ is onto and one to one.

**One to one.** Assume $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$. Then how can we see that $x=y$?

**Onto.** Assume $y\in  \left\{ x \in \mathbb N \mid x \equiv 11 \pmod{15}\right\}$. Then which $x \in \mathbb{N}$ will do the trick? How can we describe the $x$ such that $\phi(x)=y$?